# How to pass parameters to a ps1-file and then to a xml-file via powershell?

Tags: xml, powershell, parameters

I want to call this one with at least one parameter:

```
$runCMD = 'powershell.exe "C:\apache24\htdocs\data\dvelop\DataConnector_Config_prod.ps1" Parameter1 '; 
shell_exec($runCMD);
```

Then I have this ps1 (DataConnector_Config_prod.ps1):

```
$AppPath = "C:\dvelop\d.velop data connector\d.velop data connector 1.1.0.0B17.exe"
$ConfigPath = "C:\apache24\htdocs\ahock\dvelop\DataConnector_Config_abf_dvelop_produktionsplan_position.xml"
write-host "$(get-date) Start"
.$AppPath -Arguments -Config $ConfigPath 
write-host "$(get-date) End"
```

here I would like to access the parameter and I need to pass it again to XML. Sorry, but I don't now how to do this!

This is the XML-file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <dvelop-DataConnector>
      <SPSite id="1">
        <!-- Source -->
        <Source>MySQL</Source>
        <Server>192.168.1.1</Server>
        <DataSource>foo</DataSource>
        <Query>SELECT * FROM tabdata WHERE ID = 'here to state the parameter' ;</Query>
        <Username>user</Username>
        <PasswordEncrypted>xxxxxxxx</PasswordEncrypted>
        <!-- Destination -->
        <Destination>Microsoft 365</Destination>
        <DestinationClientID>xxxxxxxx</DestinationClientID>        
        <DestinationClientSecretEncrypted>xxxxxxxx</DestinationClientSecretEncrypted>
        <SPSiteURL>https://hockmsr.sharepoint.com/sites/DMS</SPSiteURL>
        <SPWebURL>https://hockmsr.sharepoint.com/sites/DMS</SPWebURL>
        <SPListURL>https://hockmsr.sharepoint.com/sites/DMS/Lists/Produktionsplan</SPListURL>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <LoggingPath>C:\dvelop\logs</LoggingPath>
        <LoggingDays>28</LoggingDays>
        <LoggingMode>Error</LoggingMode>
        <ProgramFolderPath>C:/dvelop/d.velop data connector</ProgramFolderPath>
        <!-- Additional -->
        <SleepTime>0</SleepTime>
        <ERVResponsibilityListUpdate>false</ERVResponsibilityListUpdate>
        <EventTriggeringDisable>false</EventTriggeringDisable>
        <!-- Column Mapping -->
        <Mode>All</Mode>
        <ModeRemove>false</ModeRemove>
        <AutoMapping>false</AutoMapping>
        <Column id="1">
          <SrcColumn>Titel</SrcColumn>
          <DestColumn>Title</DestColumn>
        </Column>
        <Column id="2">
          <SrcColumn>Kunde</SrcColumn>
          <DestColumn>Kunde</DestColumn>
        </Column>
...
      </SPSite>
    </dvelop-DataConnector>
```

Can you please help? I'm have not much experience with powershell.

Regards
Stefan

Comment: It might be helpful if you could share the larger goal and perhaps provide links to the documentation that brought you to this point.  The statement "I would like to access the parameter and I need to pass it again to XML" is a bit unclear. Typically, you "pass" values to executable code. XML, being a text format, doesn't actually process or act on data.

Comment: In the line "<Query>SELECT * FROM tabdata WHERE ID = 'here to state the parameter' ;</Query>" I need the ID-value of an item to update the record in the sharepoint. Until now I update the timestamp in tabdata to now() before I execute this line "<Query>SELECT * FROM tabdata ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1 ;</Query>". But it takes 10 to 15 seconds to update the sharepoint. During that time this data in tabdata could have been changed via PHP/MYSQL. So it would be good to have this SELECT executed with an unique ID of a line of that table.

Answer (score 0):

See following for parameters.  The following code will update the ID in the XML file :

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$inputFilename = "c:\temp\test.xml"
$outputFilename = "c:\temp\test1.xml"


$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($inputFilename)

$query = $doc.Descendants('Query')[0]
$where = $query.Value
$where = $where.Replace('here to state the parameter', '123')
$query.SetValue($where)

$doc.Save($outputFilename)
```

Comment: That sounds good. But unfortunately I'm not an experienced programmer. Where do I have to put this code to?

Comment: Using Notepad put code into a new file with ps1 extension.  You can then just double click file in a File Explorer.